# Does $ARMA(p,q)$ process need to be invertible and have a causal stationary solution to be written in $MA(\infty)$ representation?

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, autoregressive, moving-average

Does $ARMA(p,q)$ process need to be invertible and have a causal stationary solution to be written in $MA(\infty)$ representation?

And if you write the process in terms of $Z_t$ instead of $X_t$, then you get $AR(\infty)$ form right?

Comment: Could you explain what a "solution" to a process might be?  Your language suggests you might be thinking of some kind of possible *properties* of a process rather than any process itself.

Comment: What is the relationship between $Z_t$ and $X_t$?

Comment: @whuber - I think he's referring to the roots of the AR representation of the process being outside the unit circle.

Comment: @jbowman That sounds like a good educated guess.  It would be nice to know without having to guess ;-).

Comment: @whuber - yes, it would!

Comment: @whuber sorry about that, i meant the roots being outside the unit circle for invertibility.

Comment: @jbowman the relation is where $X_t$ and $Z_t$ are random variables in the ARMA equation

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't explain *anything at all* about the relationship between $X_t$ and $Z_t$, or, for that matter, what they are.

Comment: @jbowman $\phi_q(B)X_t = \theta_p(B)Z_t$ that's the ARMA(p,q) process